# Why I can't dereference a two dimentional array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code:

```
void main()
{
  int a[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{11,12,13,14},{21,22,23,24}};   
  printf("%d\n",*a);
  system("pause");  
}
```

The output is the address of the first element of the array. Why? I expect this address to be dereferenced.

Comment: Because it is a 2D array. you need to dereference it twice. Dereferencing once gives you address of first row/column depending on row major or column major storage of array.

Comment: `*a` means `a[0]`. This is another array. I guess you meant `a[0][0]`.

Comment: this case's first element is `[1,2,3,4]`(type is `int [4]`).

Comment: @MattMcNabb - so C implements multi D arrays as arrays of pointers? That seems a little inefficient compared to a continuous blob of memory with size H*W, which would actually give you the first element when dereferenced...

Comment: @user3735658 no, they are arrays of arrays. It is a contiguous blob of memory. That's why `a[0]` is an array and not a pointer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - I see. `&a` and `&(*a)` is the same value, so dereferencing the array does indeed return a "pointer to the first element" but dressed up as another array/pointer, thus the need to dereference twice. Hopefully the compiler optimizes that away.

Comment: `&a` and `&*a` have different types. You need to understand C's type system. You can check the assembly (in -O2 or -O3) to double check what's going on. There's 2 levels of indirection in the syntax but it is a direct memory access, just the same as using `x` in the case `int x;`

Answer (score 3):

To get the content you might want to dereference twice. The first element can be accessed by:

```
**a
```

or

```
*a[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

A multidimensional array in C is contiguous. The following:

int a[4][5];

consists of 4 int[5]s laid out next to each other in memory.

An array of pointers:

int *a[4];

is jagged. Each pointer can point to (the first element of) a separate array of a different length.

a[i][j] is equivalent to ((a+i)+j). See the C11 standard, section 6.5.2.1:

The deﬁnition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))

Thus, a[i][j] is equivalent to (*(a+i))[j], which is equivalent to ((a+i)+j).

This equivalence exists because in most contexts, expressions of array type decay to pointers to their first element (C11 standard, 6.3.2.1). a[i][j] is interpreted as the following:

a is an array of arrays, so it decays to a pointer to a[0], the first subarray.
a+i is a pointer to the ith subarray of a.
a[i] is equivalent to *(a+i), dereferencing a pointer to the ith subarray of a. Since this is an expression of array type, it decays to a pointer to a[i][0].
a[i][j] is equivalent to *(*(a+i)+j), dereferencing a pointer to the jth element of the ith subarray of a.

Note that pointers to arrays are different from pointers to their first element. a+i is a pointer to an array; it is not an expression of array type, and it does not decay, whether to a pointer to a pointer or to any other type.

and for some reason printing *a in single dimensional array will print the first element of the array whereas *a in a multidimensional array will print a random number. Why is this so?

The output is the address of the first element of the array. Why?

printf("%d\n",*a);

*a will be equivalent to a[0] that prints first element of the array.